# How can only scroll only between Indexpath.section exclude indexpath.row in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is there any way to scroll only between UICollectionView `indexpath.section` exclude `row` when `viewDidApper()` or `viewWillAppear()` called?

e.g.

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: anySectionNumber), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

Here I want to scroll only between one `indexpath.section` to another `indexpath.section` and want to avoid section `indexpath.row` when scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll from one `IndexPath.section` to another, I only adds new `items` into the `collectionView` when i needed with the use of `boolean` within the `collectionView.reloadData()` .

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
   {
        if tabSelected
        {
           return 2
        }

        else
        {
          return 1
        }
}
```

It's perfectly worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no section header then the solution you provided (scrolling to row 0 in the section) is correct.  If instead you want to scroll to a header then its a little more complicated because there isn't a method for that.  There is a method to scroll to an arbitrary rect in a scrollview: [scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible).  You can get the rect of the header by calling [layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind:at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617792-layoutattributesforsupplementary) and using the frame of the returned attributes.  (frame is in the collectionview's coordinate system).